# Play app does not seem to start unless I http to it, how can I make it start otherwise?

Tags: playframework

I have a Scala Play application with a Global which starts Actors. The problem is that the Global.onStart method does not get called until I go to my browser and http : / / l o c a l h o s t:9000/ which is the URL to my Play Framework Application. I would like it to start immediately when my application starts.

The Global is like this https://github.com/ndeverge/twivent/blob/master/app/Global.scala

Documentation on Global is here http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaGlobal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Play is run in **development** mode, i.e. with `play` and then `run` or `~run` it will start when the first request is received. [See here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/PlayConsole)

When you run in production mode (i.e. with `start` or from a dist build of your app) it will start immediately and will not check for changes before each request.